# Link formula using cell's value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a very simple question.

I want to get values from another workbook. A simple way to do this is to enter a formula like this in a cell:

```
='C:\Path\[Workbook.xlsm]Sheet1'!$D$4
```

This is working well. It returns the value in cell D4 in sheet1 in the workbook.xlsm in path directory.

As I have to treat multiple values and the path/name can change I want to stock the path/name in a cell and reuse them everywhere I need.

```
in OpenWb.xlsm, Sheet_Report, D9: 
    value: C:\Path\
    Name: Path
in OpenWb.xlsm, Sheet_Report, D10: 
    value: Workbook.xlsm
    Name: WbName
```

To use these value I wrote:

```
='Path[WbName]Sheet1'!$D$4
```

Excel gives an incorrect adress error add a [:

```
='[Path[WbName]Sheet1'!$D$4
```

When I remove the [, Excel open a file dialog box where I can select the path, name and then the sheet. It then works but it is annoying to go through these filedialog box.

How can I write the formula to go to another workbooks using cell's value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply used excel for macro:

the syntax is very simple and can be genralised to range with simple loops.

```
 Arg = "'" & Path & "[" & File & "]" & Sheet & "'!" & "R4C4" 'Range(Ref.Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1))C
     'Execute XLM macro
    GetValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro(Arg)
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use INDIRECT

```
=INDIRECT("'"&Path&"["&WbName&"]Sheet1'!$D$4")
```

but that will only work if the source workbook is open (in which case you don't need the path!). If you have the MOREFUNC add-in installed it has an INDIRECT.EXT function which is supposed to work with closed workbooks (I don't use it so can't comment from experience)

Comment: Then you need the MOREFUNC add-in or you need some code to alter the formulas, or you can use the 'edit links' option on the Data menu to simply change the source file to the one you want. There is no simple formula solution sadly.

Comment: Due to very strict internet policy in my company, I can't download add-ins easily. I'am surprised there is no solution for such a simple task.

Comment: There are solutions (I mentioned 3) but there is no simple formula for it (some would suggest that is a good thing, but that's another story)

Comment: if you can't download the add-in, then there is a function that someone else has written [here](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=312473).